# Add grouped product to category

Tags: magento-1.8

Can grouped products be added to a category? For some reason it doesn't allow me to (I've sorted by type so 'grouped' should be first alphabetically):

[image]

Am I missing something really obvious?

EDIT:

I've removed all the products from this category and added a grouped product via the database.  It doesn't show in the back end (although the count says 1) however it displays on the front end:

[image]

Why is this??

Answer (score 1):

You probably are missing some-thing as grouped products can be added to category like any other products

you can find any required help here
http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/grouped-products